# Docker image for TFS Xamarin Android build agent?

Tags: c#, xamarin, tfs

We are building `Xamarin.Android` projects on `TFS` (on-premise).

With every `Visual Studio` / `Android SDK` update we have to update all our build agents.
Is there a way to simplify this process?

There are some  [vsts-agent images](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/vsts-agent/) available, but none of them are for xamarin. There are some [xamarin](https://hub.docker.com/r/nathansamson/xamarin-android-docker/)-[related](https://hub.docker.com/r/tstivers/xamarin-android-build/) images, but they are a bit out of date (and not related to TFS).

Is there anything I'm missing? Any other solutions to the problem?

Comment: Does your agent run on Mac or Windows?

Comment: currently Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no Docker images support for xamarin or windows. Even for the existing Docker images, there are not for all TFS versions. As you can see from  [vsts-agent images](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/vsts-agent/):

> Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 are the currently supported OSes, but there are
>   plans for Windows support.
>
> When used with VSTS, the agent version is automatically determined and
>   downloaded at container startup based on the account to which the
>   agent is connecting. When used with TFS, an image that matches the
>   installed TFS version should be chosen.

There are no better way to do that. So, you have to update the build agents manually once there are any SDK updates.
You can also submit a User Voice to suggest the feature on this site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

Actually a similar user voice submitted [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17280401-docker-based-windows-build-agent),

Another workaround is migrating to VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services ) and using the hosts agent (Generally the hosts anget will be updated accordingly once new SDK/components updated, See [this user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/16751428-please-update-the-build-hosts-to-have-latest-andro)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details! Upvoted UserVoice ticket